# Interior of A-closure

Tags: general-topology

I have been working on this question.
***Let A be an open set.  Does Int(A-closure)= A?***

---

Here is my answer:

Let my space be [0,1] ∪ {2} and my topology be the subspace topology.

Let A = (0,1) ∪ {2}.

Then, A-closure = [0,1] ∪ {2}

But then, int(A-closure) = [0,1] ∪ {2} = A-closure

Hence int(A-closure) does not equal A.

Comment: Your example does not work -- if your topological space is $X=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ with the subset topology, then $2$ is certainly in the interior of $X$ itself, since $X$ contains a neighborhood of $2$, namely $X$.

Comment: So then is {2} not an isolated point?

Comment: x @Kara: $2$ is an isolated point yes -- and an isolated point _of the topological space_ is always interior in any subset it is a member of.

Comment: The interior of A is defined as the union of all open sets contained in A.  So {2} is an open set in A, so it is in the interior.  I see it now.

So A-closure = [0,1] union {2}.
Then int(A-closure) = (0,1) union {2}, which equals A.

Comment: x @Kara, actually, since $\bar A$ is the entire topological space in this case, $\bar A$ is both open and closed, and it its own interior. So your counterexample is a counterexample, just not in the way you imagined.

Comment: So wait...........are you saying that Int(A-closure) =  [0,1] union {2}?  The interior of A is defined as the union of all open sets contained in A, so the whole topological space IS an open set.  Right, ok, I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ which is open w.r.t. the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\bar{A}=[0,2]$, so int$\bar{A}=(0,2)\not= A$

Comment: OK.  Yes, I see that your example works.  Does my example given in the question also work?

Comment: Your set A is missing the point {1}, but in this case {1} is not an isolated point b/c it is not an open set, right?

Comment: That's correct.